# .htaccess redirect - Options -Indexes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, indexing

i want to turn off the indexes in the .htaccess file (Options -Indexes)
So until then it works (shows forbidden)

**And now i want to redirect to my error404 page (error404.html)**

How it works?
Thanks for help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ErrorDocument` `with 403`:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error404.html
```